# shell scripts when exceeding 100 seconds to send an email

Tags: shell-script, sed

When executing `show engine innodb status` on mysql, there are lines like `---TRANSACTION 17610C9A, ACTIVE 504 sec starting index read`.

I need a script to monitor for when the number of seconds after the `ACTIVE` keyword exceeds 100, and then send an email alert.

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
value=$(show engine innodb status | grep TRANSACTION | grep ACTIVE | \
  sed -e 's/.*ACTIVE //' -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1/')
if [ "$value" -gt 100 ]
then
  send email here
fi
```

I wasn't sure what to grep for, since it sounded like there could be other lines in the output -- the goal with the greps was to include only lines that we should look for the "ACTIVE NNN" parts in.

The sed expressions simply trim off the leading part (.* through "ACTIVE ") and then match 1 or more digits, stripping off anything after the digits. If the resulting value is strictly greater than 100, then send your email.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
detected=(
  mysql --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --raw -Be '
     show engine innodb status' | perl -ln -0777 -e '
       while (/(\*\*\* \(\d+\) TRANSACTION:\s+TRANSACTION \S+ ACTIVE (\d+).*?)(?=\*\*\*)/sg) {
         print $1 if $2 > 100;
       }'
)
if [ -n "$detected" ]; then
mailx -s "$subject" "$addresses" << EOF
Some transactions took more than 100 seconds:

$detected
EOF
fi
```

For reference, the above is adapted to the format I see which looks more like:

```
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION AE523D, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 9 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 40705, OS thread handle 0x7fa6d8197700, query id 5697977 localhost bugs updating
DELETE FROM tokens WHERE token = 'JpLgGK5Ygn'
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 32823 n bits 280 index `PRIMARY` of table `bugs`.`tokens` trx id AE523D lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 212 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 10; hex 4a704c67474b3559676e; asc JpLgGK5Ygn;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000ae523b; asc     R;;;
 2: len 7; hex 6c0000c01f0572; asc l     r;;
 3: len 3; hex 80000f; asc    ;;
 4: len 8; hex 80001255ef969792; asc    U    ;;
 5: len 7; hex 73657373696f6e; asc session;;
 6: len 17; hex 6372656174655f6174746163686d656e74; asc create_attachment;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
```